# Limit Question with trigonometric and exponentials

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been stuck on this limit question for quite some time. 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin(x)}{(x+1)(\ln(x))}$$
I have tried substituting $x=e^{-y}$ and $1+x=e^y$ to no avail. This only gives: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{e^{-y}}{-y(e^{-y}+1)}$$
and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{y}-1}{e^y(\ln(e^{y}-1))}$$ respectively. In both cases I took out $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ of the limit to get $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{(x+1)(\ln(x))}$$. I have no idea how else I can reduce this limit so I can find the answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First, $x+1 \to 1$, so forget that. Now, how do $\sin$ and $\ln$ behave for $x\to 0$?

Comment: If you sub $x=e^{-y}$, then $x\to 0$ means $y\to\infty$.

Comment: Yep sorry corrected

Comment: I can get it down to $lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{ln(x)}$

Comment: Got it sorted thanks, without removing the $sin(x)$ we have $lim_{x\to0}\frac{sin(x)}{ln(x)}$. Since $ln(0)\rightarrow-\infty$ and $sin(x)$ stays between -1 and 1, then the limit will tend to zero. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to know that, if $x \to 0$, then $1 + x \sim 1 $, $\sin x \sim x$

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{(x+1)(\ln(x))} \sim  \frac{x}{\ln(x)}$$

$x \to 0, \ln x \to -\infty$, so the limit is $0$ (it is not an indeterminate form)

Comment: Thanks makes sense. Is $\frac{\infty}{0}$ indeterminate?

Comment: no.. think it this way: $\frac{\infty}{0} = \infty \cdot \frac{1}{0} = \infty \cdot \infty = \infty$

Comment: @George1811 It is not. $\infty \times \frac{1}{0}=\infty \times \infty= \infty$

Comment: Ah! I see, thanks.

Comment: you're welcome! If you like this answer, please vote and accept it ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

As ln(x) tends to $-\infty$ , the limit is simply 0.